# Updating database when using View Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a question abou view models and adding information to a database.

Let's say i have these two classes:

```
public class Ad {
public int Id { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public string Headline { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public int Type { get; set; }

public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public int CategoryName { get; set; }

public IColletion<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
}

Context class:
public DbSet<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

The models are really over simpified but i just want to get a grasp of the context. Lets say i want to create a view model for the view that are suppose to add entries to the db. How do i go about adding info to the "Ads" database table from a view model. Lets say the view model looks something like:

```
namespace Website.Models
{
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public Ad Ad { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> AdTypes { get; set; }

    public CreateViewModel()
    {
        // to populate a dropdown on the "Create" page
        this.Adtypes= new Dictionary<int, string>
                              {
                                  {1, "For sale"},
                                  {2, "Want to buy"},
                                  {3, "Want to trade"},
                                  {4, "Have to offer"}
                              };
    }
}
}
```

The only thing i really need when adding to the db is the parameters in the Ad class (although i need the view model to render the dropdowns). But how do I extract this from the CreateViewModel to add to the db.

This is my code at the moment:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Ad ad)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Ads.Add(ad);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(ad);
```

Since this is expecting a Ad class, how do i extract only the Ad paramaters from the view model and insert it to the db.
Sorry, very long post and probably some serious newbie stuff. I just didn't know how to explain it better.

I would appreciate if someone could explain about view models, or direct me to some site that does.

/m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Viewmodels when you need more data on the website like values for dropdowns. So lets say you want to create a car.

Car object (Car.cs)

```cs
public class Car
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Color {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

But you don't want to type color by yourself in a textbox. Let's say you want to pick color from dropdown. If so you need to add somehow list (SelectList) of colors to a dropdown.

Viewmodel is helpful in this situation (CreateCarViewModel.cs)

```cs
public CreateCarViewModel
{
  public Car Car {get;set;}
  public SelectList Colors{ get; set; } //List of colors for dropdown
}
```

Controller

```cs
ActionResult CreateCar()
{
  CreateCarViewModel CCVM = new CreateCarViewModel();  
  List<string> colors = new List<string>{"Black","White"};
  CCVM.Colors = new SelectList(colors);

  //Your view is expecting CreateCarViewModel object so you have to pass it
  return View(CCVM);
}
```

CreateCar (CreateCar.cshtml)

```cs
@model YourSolutionName.ModelsFolder.CreateCarViewModel

//form etc.
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Car.Color, Model.Colors)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Car.Name)
}
```

Controller Again

```cs
[HttpPost]
//Again: but now controller expects CreateCarViewModel
ActionResult CreateCar(CreateCarViewModel CCVM)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    //update database with CCVM.Car object and redirect to some action or whatever you want to do
  else
  {
    //populate your colors list again

    List<string> colors = new List<string>{"Black","White"};
    CCVM.Colors = new SelectList(colors);
    return View (CCVM);
  }
}
```

Comment: Mariusz: Thanks alot for an excellent explanation. I was kinda thinking in these directions but i could never get it to work. This will surely help me out though!